# Including method body in a room Dao method

Tags: android, android-room

```
@Insert
void insert(User user);
```

Method above is taken from a Room Dao class and it inserts given User to database. It has no body but the code required to do the insert is generated at compile time I think.

Now, if I add a body to it like below, does it lose the functionality of inserting user? Or does it both insert user and run foo ?

```
@Insert
void insert(User user){
   foo(); //stuff
}
```

Comment: Well, why you don't test it by your self?

Comment: dunno ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dao classes are most commonly interfaces.

You cannot add implementations (body) in interfaces.

More info on interfaces: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

You could make it abstract, but it wouldn't make much sense since no insertion would occur. If insert method is not abstract itself, it already has an implementation and Room would ignore it. As far as I've tested it, it doesn't work.

Comment: No I am sure you can make a Dao class abstract instead

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction How does this work then

Comment: My bad. You can declare it as abstract and have an implementation. See updated answer.